# How to set checkbox to a custom text in string and save into database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-checkbox

I am working on `android`. I have a checkbox in my `app` and I want to save a custom text against my checkbox when it is checked or not.

```
CheckBox atbSealedCheckBox;
String selectedAtbSealedValue ="";
atbSealedCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.atbCheckBox);
```

Now, If I checked the `checkbox` then I want to store `Yes` otherwise `No`. Also, I want to store it in my DB. For this I have already created `get` and `set` methods in my `Model`

```
private String atbSealed;

public String getAtbSealed(){return atbSealed;}

public void setAtbSealed(String atbSealed){this.atbSealed=atbSealed;}
```

**Update 1**

As per suggestion, I have tried below

```
atbSealedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if(isatbSealedChecked)
            {
                selectedAtbSealedValue = "Yes";
                ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(false);
                ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
                isatbSealedChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedAtbSealedValue = "No";
                ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(true);
                ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
                isatbSealedChecked = false;
            }

        }
    });
```

But It doesn't help me out. Also, the `ctQuantitySpinner` is not disabled on `atbSealedCheckbox` checked. Also if checked the boolean value of the checkbox is not changed to `true`. Although in `log` I do see the `selectedAtbSealedValue` but it's not set in the app. In my `SaveDataLocal()` function I have set the value like below

```
 survey.setAtbSealed(this.selectedAtbSealedValue);
 SurveyManager dbHelper = new SurveyManager(getActivity());
    dbHelper.addSurvey(survey);
```

I have also tried the below code

```
 atbSealedCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
            {
                ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(false);
                ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);

                selectedAtbSealedValue = "Yes";
                isatbSealedChecked = true;
                //atbCheckBoxEdittext.setText(selectedAtbCheckBox);
            }
            else {
                ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(true);
                ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
                selectedAtbSealedValue = "No";
                isatbSealedChecked = false;
                //atbCheckBoxEdittext.setText(selectedAtbCheckBox);
            }
        }
    });
```

This code shows me the `selected checkbox value`, disabled the `spinner` and set the spinner value to `null`. but again the checkbox value is not saved.

How can I save custom text in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it work for me:

```
atbSealedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ) {
            if (isChecked) {
               selectedAtbSealedValue = "yes";
            } else {
               selectedAtbSealedValue = "no";
            }
        }
    } );
```

After that, you can store `selectedAtbSealedValue` into DB;

**Update**: Your fixed code:

```js
atbSealedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        if(b)
        {
            selectedAtbSealedValue = "Yes";
            ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(false);
            ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
            isatbSealedChecked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedAtbSealedValue = "No";
            ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(true);
            ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
            isatbSealedChecked = false;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: You try Log for value of `selectedAtbSealedValue`

Comment: Yes it's empty in either case

Comment: sure i'll add it

Comment: Why you don't use `boolean b`, `b = true` is checked, `b=false` is unchecked

Comment: if(b)
            {
                selectedAtbSealedValue = "Yes";
                ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(false);
                ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
                isatbSealedChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedAtbSealedValue = "No";
                ctQuantitySpinner.setEnabled(true);
                ctQuantitySpinner.setSelection(0);
                isatbSealedChecked = false;
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167595/discussion-between-mr-faisal-and-meoscoder).

Comment: Please come on chat

Comment: `private CheckBox atbSealedCheckBox;
private String selectedAtbSealedValue ="";`

this is global variables

Comment: `private String selectedAtbSealedValue ="";` put this outside onCreate() (global variable). It can't change value to yes or no because it auto convert to final variable in onCreate()

Comment: Yes they both are `global`

Comment: And not final ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand your question, you want to change this variable `String selectedAtbSealedValue ="";` when user checked your checkbox.

To achieve this statement, you can use onCheckedListener that is triggered as soon as users checked or removed the check from your checkbox.

```
atbSealedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ) {
                // Todo something.
            }
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.
At submit button get the current value of checkbox.

```
 submit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            control_of_vectors_value = control_of_vectors_checkbox.isChecked() == true ? "yes" : "no";  }}
```